# Как получить реальную локаль в jsp-странице

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jsp

Задача выглядит так: для русского и английского языка должна отображаться страница с чужого сайта, для немецкого: страница, которая написана мной. 
Задаю так:

```
            <c:set var="localeCode" value="${fn:toUpperCase(pageContext.response.locale)}" />
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${localeCode == 'DE' }">
               <li><a href="<spring:message code="otcHeader.externalLink5.source" />" target="_blank"><spring:message code="otcHeader.externalLink5.text" /></a></li>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
               <li><a href="<c:url value="/contact"/>"><spring:message code="otcHeader.externalLink5.text" /></a></li>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:when>
```

Странно работает. Когда только запускаю с немецким по умолчанию, я получаю немецкую локаль, но стоит поменять язык, как test начинает возвращает false всегда и я получаю свою страницу, хотя снова переключаюсь на немецкий. Причем даже не помогает перезагрузка страницы, только перезагрузка сервера. Что происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что localeCode сначала получает значение DE, а после перехода на другой язык и обратно DE_DE . Проблема решилась выборкой подстроки из 2-х символов.